# Cocoapods Traceback Could not find 'json' (>= 1.5.1) among 41 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, cocoapods

I've recently installed cocoapods through Homebrew,
after install I want to run or install pods, once I execute pod command in terminal it shows this error bellow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `activate_bin_path'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `synchronize'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1371:in `activate'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1389:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1389:in `each'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1403:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1371:in `activate'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1389:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1389:in `each'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1403:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1371:in `activate'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1389:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1389:in `each'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1400:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'json' (>= 1.5.1) among 41 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/mustafaalkhazraji/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0/libexec:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```